# Git: how to undo merge during rebase

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I've made a pull with rebase:

```
git pull --rebase
```

After two commits were successfully applied I started applying the third one. It the middle of this I realized that I did it wrong and it would be good to undo it. Of course I can do git

```
rebase --abort
```

but then I'll loose all the work I've done (two applied commits).

Is there any way to undo the process of applying current commit during rebase and start merging again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a

```
git rebase --skip
```

(perhaps multiple times)

That way, your applied commits will be saved. However at that point your third commit will be hidden, so follow up with:

```
git branch old-commit ORIG_HEAD
```

to have access to your other (third an following) commits.

For finishing touch, you could do

```
git checkout old-commit && git rebase --interactive HEAD...master
```

and remove the successfully rebased commits.

Comment: And after that I should do "git pull --rebase" again. Right?

Comment: To rebase the rest of your commits, yes (if you want to continue right away, you could skip the rebase interactive, since the next pull would throw away your already rebased commits)